# MVC3 VS2010 Application Settings i9mplementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, implementation, application-settings

I have an MVC2 C#.Net web app using VS2010.  Below is an entry in y web.config:

```
<configuration>
     <applicationSettings>
       <BOE.My.MySettings>
         <setting name="AppBackColor" serializeAs="String">
           <value>AntiqueWhite</value>
         </setting>
       </BOE.My.MySettings>
     </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

However, in my Controler.cs file My.Settings.AppBackColor is unrecognized.  Any ideas?

```
var backColor= My.Settings.AppBackColor
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by unrecognized, you face a compiler error, runtime error or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Desktop application stuff. In web applications you don't use such settings.

You could use the `<appSettings>` section of your web.config to store custom values:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="bar" />
</appSettings>
```

and then when you want to read `foo`:

```
var foo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"];
```

Comment: @Darin....I was hoping to get away from using strings in code.  I've seen <ApplicationSetting> used in other web apps.  But, it was so different from what I needed that I couldn't use it